# Reverse Finished Animation angular

Tags: angular, animation

How can I reverse the animation from the end point, instead of restarting the animation from the start:
:leave wont work cause the element isnt leaving the dom.

```
trigger('zoomAndMove', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({
          'background-size': '150%',
          'background-position': '95% center',
        }),
        animate(
          '6s ease-in-out',
          style({
            'background-size': '150%',
            'background-position': '90% center',
          })
        ),
        animate(
          '6s ease-in-out',
          style({
            'background-size': '170%',
            'background-position': '10% 20%',
          })
        ),
        animate(
          '6s ease-in-out',
          style({
            'background-size': '200%',
            'background-position': '20% 150%',
          })
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use keyframes

```
trigger('zoomAndMove', [
    transition(':enter', [
        animate('24s ease-in-out', keyframes([
            style({
                'background-size': '150%',
                'background-position': '95% center',
                offset: 0
            }),
            style({
                'background-size': '150%',
                'background-position': '90% center',
                offset: 0.25
            }),
            style({
                'background-size': '170%',
                'background-position': '10% 20%',
                offset: 0.5
            }),
            style({
                'background-size': '200%',
                'background-position': '20% 150%',
                offset: 0.75
            }),
            style({
                'background-size': '150%',
                'background-position': '95% center',
                offset: 1
            })
        ]))
    ])
])
```